# Where is the Best Placement for Breadcrumb, top or bottom?

Tags: website-design, best-practice, placement, breadcrumbs

Usually I see that every website put their breadcrumb on the top, but apple put their breadcrumb on the bottom before the footer.

[image]

Does that work better than when we put it on the top?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

TL;DR: **Top**, or both.

---

[Nielsen notes that](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/breadcrumb-navigation-useful/) *consistency breeds familiarity*, so you should comply with conventions to meet user expectations:

> This consistency means that people know a breadcrumb trail when they see one, and immediately know how to use it. Consistency breeds familiarity and predictability, which breed usability. This again means that **you must comply with conventions in the design of your own breadcrumbs**.

More often than not, the user will look for the breadcrumbs **immediately below the main navigation**, because this is where they're most commonly found.

[A search of Google Images for the term "website breadcrumbs"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=website%20breadcrumbs) shows just how common it is to find breadcrumbs at the top:

[image: Google Images search for Website Breadcrumbs]

---

### Why do Apple put it at the bottom?

**So the user doesn't have to scroll back up to the top.**

Apple tend to have very long pages, so putting it at the bottom is helpful.

However, **putting it in both locations** would serve both the expectations of the user, and aid those needing to locate themselves after reaching the end of the page.

Apple does this by:

- Showing traditional breadcrumbs at the bottom
- Highlighting the selected items in the main navigation at the top.

  - This provides the same functionality as breadcrumbs.

[image: Apple Top Breadcrumbs]
[image: Apple Bottom Breadcrumbs]

Comment: why does apple place it below? I agree it should be placed below main navigation.

Comment: My apologies, I submitted my answer early so I hadn't yet put the explanation to that. It's now in my answer.

Comment: _Functionally_, if it's not in a fixed header, "_bottom_ or both" would often be better (since you're often at/near the bottom when you want to go elsewhere), but as you say, familiarity is generally more important still. Perhaps I'd go with "_Fixed to the top_ or both".

Comment: Generally the point I'm trying to make is that *both is better* :)